# checked check box count

Tags: javascript

How do I count the number of checked checkboxes in a `div`?

Answer (score 9):

```
var count = 0;
var inputs = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i<j; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type && input.type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have JQuery on your site you can do it this way (assuming yor div has id='myDiv'):

`$("#myDiv input:checkbox:checked").length`